# documentclass: toc= bib _and_ listof

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm having a document with list of figures, list of tabels (both after contents) and, in the end of the document, list of references.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,titlepage, toc=bib]{scrbook}
```

I'd like to include a reference to each of the three lists in the list of contents, therefore I'd need to add multiple parameters to toc=... , which i don't know how to achieve, like:

```
toc=bib, listof
```

Is there a possibility to add both parameters (bib and listof) to toc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `toc=<selection>`, to the comma separated list of class options, for each desired option:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,titlepage,toc=listof,toc=bib]{scrbook} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{A} Test.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]